# conexion php para guardar este formulario

Tags: php, html, mysql

tengo el siguiente formulario: y necesito guardarlo en una base de datos que se llame guardar.php, pero el archivo php no estoy seguro de como hacerlo para guardar toda esta informacion con todos estos campos, los trate de guardar al principio en las varialbes nombre, materno, paternos, matricula, sexo, tipolicencia, nacimientoMes, selcombo, birthday_year y despues trate de crear una variable llamada db que es igual a un mysql_select_db que llama a la tabla llamada altas donde estan estos campos y llama a una variable llamada conexion que, al principio solo hace conexion con la base de datos, despues hice un insert into a las altas con el nombre de todos los campos y las values entre comillas simples con el nombre de las varialbes que estan arriba, despues puse que hiciera un query con la variable consulta que es lo que hace el inser into, pero cuando lo ejecuto, todas las variables que hice al inicio me marca error xampp y no estoy seguro porque, alguna ayuda con esto? somos 3 personas y ninguno nos puede dar esto haha apenas estamos aprendiendo, esto es lo que tenemos en el codigo de php:

```
<?php
$conexion=mysql_connect("localhost","root","","bdlogin");

$nombre=$_post["nombre"];
$materno=$_post["materno"];
$paterno=$_post["paterno"];
$matricula=$_post["matricula"];
$sexo=$_post["sexo"];
$tipolicencia=$_post["tipoLicencia"];
$nacimientoMes=$_post["nacimientoMes"];
$selcombo=$_post["selCombo"];
$birthday_year=$_post["birthday_year"];

$db=mysql_select_db("altas",$conexion);
$consulta="insert into altas(nombre, materno, paterno, edad, matricula, sexo, licencia, mes, dia, anio) VALUES('$nombre','$materno','$paterno','$matricula','$sexo','$tipolicencia','$nacimiento','$selcombo','$birthday_year')";
$res=mysql_query($consulta);
mysql_close($conexion);
?>
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
p {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.wrapper {
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
  overflow:hidden;
}
header {
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.9);
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 10;
}

nav {
  float: left;
}
nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  overflow: hidden; 
}
nav ul li {
  float: left;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
}
nav ul li a {
  display: block; 
  padding: 20px;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}
nav ul li:hover {
  background: #3ead47;
}
.contenido {
  padding-top: 80px;
}
#informacion{
  width: auto;
  background-color: gray;
  margin-top: 5%;
  margin-left: 20%;
  margin-right: 20%;
  margin-bottom: auto;
}
#lasAltas{
  width: auto;
  background-color: gray;
  margin-top: 3%;
  margin-left: 1%;
  margin-right: 55%;
  margin-bottom: auto;
  justify-content: center;
}
input{
  margin: 1%;
  background: lightgray;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" action="guardar.php" id="lasAltas">
   <ol>dar de alta</ol>
    <div><input name="nombre" id="nombreAlta" type="text" placeholder="nombre"></div>
    <div><input name="materno" id="maternoAlta"type="text" placeholder="apellido materno"></div>
    <div><input name="paterno" id="paternoAlta"type="text" placeholder="apellido paterno"></div>
    <div><input name="edad" id="edadAlta"type="text" placeholder="edad"></div>
    <div><input name="matricula" id="matricula" type="text" placeholder="matricula vehicular"></div>
    <div><input name="sexo"type="radio">hombre <input name="sexo" type="radio">mujer</div>
    <ol>tipo de licencia</ol>
       <div><select name="tipoLicencia" id="Licencia">
        <option value="A">A</option>
        <option value="B">B</option>
    </select></div>
    <h4>fecha de nacimiento</h4>
    <select name="nacimientoMes" id="nacimientoMes">
        <option value="">mes</option>
        <option value="enero">enero</option>
        <option value="febrero">febrero</option>
    </select>
    <select NAME="selCombo" id="diaAuto">dia
    <option value="">dia</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    </select>
    <select name="birthday_year" id="year" >
    <option value="0">Año</option>
    <option value="2019">2019</option>
    <option value="2018">2018</option>
    <option value="2017">2017</option>
    <option value="2016">2016</option>
    <option value="2015">2015</option>
    <option value="2014">2014</option>
    <option value="2013">2013</option>
    <option value="2012">2012</option>
    <option value="2011">2011</option>
    <option value="2010">2010</option>
    <option value="2009">2009</option>
    <option value="2008">2008</option>
    <option value="2007">2007</option>
    <option value="2006">2006</option>
    <option value="2005">2005</option>
    <option value="2004">2004</option>
    <option value="2003">2003</option>
    <option value="2002">2002</option>
    <option value="2001">2001</option>
    <option value="2000">2000</option>
    <option value="1999">1999</option>
    <option value="1998">1998</option>
    <option value="1997">1997</option>
    <option value="1996">1996</option>
    <option value="1995">1995</option>
    <option value="1994">1994</option>
    <option value="1993">1993</option>
    <option value="1992">1992</option>
    <option value="1991">1991</option>
    <option value="1990">1990</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="guardar datos">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Por favor no edites la respuesta de quien te esta auxiliando con detalles como el error que obtuviste al aplicarla, puedes dejarle un comentario debajo de la respuesta o editar tu pregunta agregando detalles nuevos

Answer (score 1):

```html
<?php
//mysqli_connect se utiliza para conectar al servidor!
$conexion=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","");


// Recibes los datos que enviastes con la petición POST y los guardas en una variable.

$nombre=$_POST["nombre"];
$materno=$_POST["materno"];
$paterno=$_POST["paterno"];
$matricula=$_POST["matricula"];
$sexo=$_POST["sexo"];
$tipolicencia=$_POST["tipoLicencia"];
$nacimientoMes=$_POST["nacimientoMes"];
$selcombo=$_POST["selCombo"];
$birthday_year=$_POST["birthday_year"];


//mysqli_select_db esta función selecciona la base de datos agregándole 2 parámetros el nombre de la base de datos y conexión que guardas en la variable $conexion

$db=mysqli_select_db("TuBaseDeDatos",$conexion);


//Creas tu query y la guardas en la variable $consulta
$consulta="INSERT INTO TuTabla(nombre,materno, paterno, edad, matricula, sexo, licencia, mes, dia, anio) VALUES('$nombre','$materno','$paterno','$matricula','$sexo','$tipolicencia','$nacimiento','$selcombo','$birthday_year')";

//Con la función mysqli_query ejecutas la query que se guarda en la variable $consulta y guardas el resultado que sera true(exitoso) o false(error) en la variable $res.
$res=mysqli_query($consulta);

// Si la query es exitosa la función mysqli_query devolverá true, en caso contrario false y ocupamos un if que se ejecutara si la expresión es verdadera .

if($res){
    echo "insertado!";
}
else{
    echo "error al ingresar!"
}

mysqli_close($conexion);
?>
```

PD: hay varias formas de conectar a una base de datos MYSQL y se ocupan las siguientes api(interfaz de programación de aplicaciones).

las api están compuestas por funciones que permiten generar cierta abstracción y en la cual tu sabes que hace la función y que parámetros necesita , sin preocuparte del como lo hace internamente.

1-**mysql**(fue el primer api obsoleta desde la versión 5.5)

2-**mysqli**(Esta api agrega mejoras con respecto a programación orientada a objetos)

3-**pdo**(genera una abstracción que permite acceder a diferentes sistemas de base de datos)

**error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_connect()**,  ,te esta diciendo que estas llamando a una función que no esta definida y este error se genera porque en realidad la **api mysql** quedo obsoleta desde la **versión 5.5** , así que para este propósito tendrás que utilizar la **api mysqli** , como vez a todos las funciones **mysql** la remplaze por **mysqli** ,simplemente.

Ejemplo:

mysql_connect() | mysqli_connect()

mysql_query()   | mysqli_query()